# Testing for weak instrument

Tags: stata, instrumental-variable

I have 3 endogenous variables in my model and I have identified 3 (or max 4) instruments. I wanted to know appropriate test for identifying whether the instruments are weak or not given that I have heteroskedaticity (cluster option is being used) in my data. I read that one should employ the Kleibergen-Paap F statistic in this case and compare with Stock and Yogo Critical values but in the case of 3 endogenous variables the table in their paper starts with a min of 5 instruments. I am confused as to which test to employ in this case. Any suggestions would be useful in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

> Staiger and Stock (1997) formalized the definition of “weak
>   instruments” and most researchers seem to have concluded (incorrectly)
>   from that work (or hearsay) that if the F-statistic on the excluded
>   instruments in the first stage is greater than 10, one need worry no
>   further about weak instruments.Stock and Yogo (2005) go into more
>   detail and provide useful rules of thumb regarding the weakness of
>   instruments based on a statistic due to Cragg and Donald (1993).
>   Stock, Wright, and Yogo (2002) provide a summary of this work.

[Weak instruments:  An overview and new techniques](https://www.stata.com/meeting/5nasug/wiv.pdf)

Austin Nichols (2006)

While an  F-statistic cutoff of 10 may be a crude rule of thumb and not sufficient to conclude that a set of instruments are not weak, Stock, Wright, and Yogo (2002) have a table about weak instrument cutoff values that goes down to 1 instrument.
[image]
[GMM, Weak Instruments, and Weak Identification](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a4c8/275a5f64d44ff78451197f9a31200f68d542.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for you reply. The table that you have shared from their 2002 version of the paper is a subset of the larger table given in the 2005 paper. This table gives critical value in case of one endogenous variable, but I have 3 endogenous variables and with latter the critical values are given when the model has at least 5 instruments.